# Android product flavors versionNameSuffix

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using buildTypes and productFlavors. My app also uses an analytics tool and this tool used the versionName of my app.

How can I change the versionName per flavor? My test was

```
productFlavors {
    google {
        versionNameSuffix ".google"
    }
}
```

but it failed. Does anybody has an idea how to custom the versionName depending on the flavor?

**Update**

Apparently the `2.2.0` version of Gradle Android plugin now allows setting `versionNameSuffix` in `productFlavors`

Comment: Any luck? Got `Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'versionNameSuffix()'` when I try

Comment: Your update saved my time . thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is still a work in progress for me, but seems to work:

```
productFlavors {
    development {
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + (System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ? "-build" + System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer : "-developerBuild")
    }
}
```

So we can set the versionName in defaultConfig, on the build server it sets the environmental variable BUILD_NUMBER, so ends up being like: `1.2-build1234`  The production build only uses the defaultConfig so is just `1.2`, and when building on dev machines the environmental variable isn't set so its `1.2-developerBuild`

Just came up with this plan tonight (so could be simplified i'm sure), so working on getting the latest source control revision added when on a dev machine, but i've seen other answers with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the entire version name through a flavor, like this:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor_a {
        versionName 'Version_A'
    }
    flavor_b {
        versionName 'Version_B'
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    versionName 'Default_version_name'
}
```

If a flavor doesn't specify a version name, it will pick it up from `defaultConfig`.